# How does Selecor selects any element with xpath within object of requests module

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, python-requests, selector, concurrent.futures

Please have a look at chunk of code first

```
r = requests.get(url,headers={"User_Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"})
    #print(r.content)
    sku = Selector(text=r.text).xpath('.//div/@data-sku').extract_first()
    print(sku)
```

In this code, I am trying to get some information written clearly on a webpage. The link is stored in `url` variable.
If I check the xpath of the element manually, the xpath is `(//*[@id="shop-products"]/li[1]/div[2]/p[1])`.
But as the code says, xpath is different, something else, but it is working literally fine.

Why does this happen? 
I am attaching chunk of html as well as an image.

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've edited your question to use Markdown formatting and made some other minor changes.

Comment: Check `.//div/@data-sku` manually in the browser devtools.